# How do I switch my Windows 10 desktop *out* of list view?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop

I'm running Windows 10 (Enterprise, 21H1), and, for unknown reasons earlier this morning, the desktop began displaying in list view. I understand that many people love this, and so the general advice being sought is how to enable it (apparently this feature was removed at some point in Windows 10?). I, however, am looking to *disable* it.

My desktop now has a bar running across the top (of all three monitors) with column headers (Name, Size, Item type, Date modified) that I can click on to sort the icons. Furthermore, the icons all have checkboxes (though this is not the case on any other Explorer window or folder), and folders do *not* show up on the desktop (though they do if I open the Desktop folder in an Explorer window).

[image: screenshot of top-left corner of leftmost monitor]

I can change the view to large icons, medium icons, small icons, etc, and this has no effect (other than to hide the icons unless I choose "tile" mode). The bar across the top and the checkboxes remain in all modes.

I have run the sfc tool, and while this found minor issues (mainly some ACL overlaps and a problem with a start menu link), it did not correct the problem.

How in the world do I get my desktop back to "normal" view?

Additional information:

I rebooted in safe mode to see if the behavior happened there, and while the checkboxes were present there, the sort bar across the top was not. I then rebooted in normal mode, and the behavior from safe mode has persisted into normal mode, with the additional change that the OneDrive status icons are now present (green checkmarks in the lower left corner). Overall, this is an improvement, but we're not totally there yet.

[image: Desktop screenshot showing OneDrive status icons]

Comment: Any way we can have a screenshot of this behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound sure, I added a screenshot.

Comment: With zero folders open hit Ctrl + Shift + 4 with an icon selected

Comment: @Ramhound that made the icons smaller, nothing else changed.

Comment: I don’t have a VM in front of me so try [Ctrl + Shift + 8](https://winaero.com/set-details-content-or-list-view-for-desktop-icons-in-windows-10/#:~:text=Set%20Details%2C%20Content%20or%20List%20view%20for%20Desktop,%2B%203%20Medium%20Icons%20Ctrl%20%2B%20...%20) instead

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+8 makes the icons bigger (than Ctrl+Shift+4), nothing else changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129237/discussion-between-ramhound-and-mark).

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Sort of... I updated the question with details.

Comment: So what's left is getting rid of the checkbooks?

Comment: Check  File Explorer > View. Disable Item check boxes to disable the check box.

Comment: @harrymc "Item check boxes" is not enabled.

Comment: Check these [two methods](https://www.howtogeek.com/666235/how-to-remove-checkboxes-in-file-explorer-on-windows-10/). Check also the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`, if item `AutoCheckSelect` is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the [FolderFlags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderflags) value for the Desktop view has been corrupted. Open regedit & navigate to:
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`
and check the value of **`"FFlags"`**. It should have a value that's unique to the Desktop: `0x40000224` `(1073742372)`.

If it doesn't, do the following:

1. Start **Task Manager**
2. Start an ***Admin* PowerShell** console
3. Locate **Windows Explorer** in **Task Manager** (far down the list)
4. Select > right-click > `End task`
5. Alt+tab to **regedit** and delete the **`Desktop`** key
6. Alt+tab to **PowerShell**, type `explorer<Enter>` to restart the shell.
7. Hopefully the Desktop is back to normal.

Comment: Awesome! My FFlags value was 0x407583b4; updating it to 0x40000224 and restarting Explorer was sufficient to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback & marking my reply as "Answer". Would love to know how all those flags got set. For the curious, your Desktop had all these set: `SnapToGrid`, `BesTfitWindow`, `Desktop`, `NoSubfolders`, `Transparent`, `NoClientedge`, `SingleClickActivate`, `NoWebView`, `CheckSelect`, `NoGrouping`, `FullRowSelect`, `NoFilters`, `UseSearchFolder`. The default set is: `SnapToGrid`, `Desktop`, `NoClientedge`, `UseSearchFolder`.

Comment: Hey, that's awesome. I poked around to see if I could figure out what flags were set, but I didn't see them listed anywhere. Thanks for the information!

Comment: You saw the link to the enumeration in my answer, right? I copied that and went at it with some interactive string manipulation to get name/value pairs that I used to create an `Add-Type` statement that allowed me to get the strings  above by casting the value as the enumeration type: `[FWF]0x407583b4`